# Why does my db read block my play framework server?

Tags: database, scala, playframework, threadpool, blocking

I have a mySQL db hosted on AWS RDS and Play framework server using AWS EC2 instance.
All of my other API endpoints work fine, but every time multiple connections are made to my db, my server seems to shut down for a while. I did some research and I think it might have something to do with thread pools or the request is getting blocked. This is my action code:

```
def getDataFromDB = Action {
  val conn = db.getConnection()
  var qJsonArray: JsArray = Json.arr()

  try {
    val stmt = conn.createStatement
    val query = "SELECT * FROM table"
    val rs = stmt.executeQuery(query)
    val rsmd = rs.getMetaData
    val columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount

    while (rs.next) {
      var index = 1

      var rsJson: JsObject = Json.obj()
      while (index <= columnCount) {
        val column = rsmd.getColumnLabel(index)
        val columnLabel = column.toLowerCase()
        val value = rs.getObject(column)

        if (value == null) {
          rsJson = rsJson ++ Json.obj(
            columnLabel -> JsNull
          )
        } else if (value.isInstanceOf[Integer]) {
          rsJson = rsJson ++ Json.obj(
            columnLabel -> value.asInstanceOf[Int]
          ) 
        } else if (value.isInstanceOf[String]) {
          rsJson = rsJson ++ Json.obj(
            columnLabel -> value.asInstanceOf[String]
          )
        } else if (value.isInstanceOf[Date]) {
          rsJson = rsJson ++ Json.obj(
            columnLabel -> value.asInstanceOf[Date].getTime
          )
        } else {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("oh no")
        }
        index += 1
      }
      qJsonArray = qJsonArray :+ rsJson
    }
  } finally {
    conn.close()
  }
  Ok(qJsonArray)
}
```

Comment: Do you have to create new connection for every query? Check if the connection class is thread safe or not. May be you can create only one connection and use it multiple times

Comment: @MahmoudHanafy I'm not sure actually. I am using this call to display some data on my front end, and want to scale to hundreds of client connections. Is it okay (and safe) to keep the connection open all the time?